# Why can taskmaanger as an administrator kill nssm.exe as a System?

Tags: windows, permissions

**OS : Windows 10** 
**Nssm Download Link** : https://nssm.cc/ (management service software)

**Explain :** 
I use the administrator to open taskmannger. 
Use taskmannger to kill the nssm.exe process.

**Problem :** 
Why taskmannger is an administrator process, but can kill the nssm.exe(system process) ? 
The system authority is higher than that of the administrator.